# Tests are failing in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github-actions

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: C/C++ CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: configure
      run: chmod u+x configure;./configure

    - name: Build code using cmake
      run: |
       cmake -S . -B build
       cd build && make
       
    - name: Run 00_constructor_tests
      run:
        ./tests/00_constructor_tests/00_runHW05ConstructorTest
      
    - name: Run 01_billType_tests
      run: 
        ./tests/01_billType_tests/01_runHW05BillTypeTest
      
    - name: Run 02_dateType_tests
      run:
        ./tests/02_dateType_tests/02_runHW05DateTypeTest
      
    - name: Run 03_doctorType_tests
      run:
        ./tests/03_doctorType_tests/03_runHW05DoctorTypeTest
      
    - name: Run 04_patientType_tests
      run:
        ./tests/04_patientType_tests/04_runHW05PatientTypeTest
hw05-classes-and-inheritance-michaelzgq/hw05_tests.yml at main · saddleback-college-cs1b/hw05-classes-and-inheritance-michaelzgq
```

It's failing with this error:

> /home/runner/work/_temp/38b5b410-8a78-44f2-8d1d-06b7efe9e6c0.sh: line 1: ./tests/00_constructor_tests/00_runHW05ConstructorTest: No such file or directory
> Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

Comment: Are you sure that running `make` also builds the tests? Seems like it's not building tests or the generated binaries' names differ. Please check and verify your Cmake config and include the relevant parts showing that it does build tests running `make` only. Also, mention how you build it locally. Thanks!